# How to find only parent ul elements in a deeply nested ul-li span structure

Tags: jquery, html, parent

I need help in traversing up a deeply nested ul-li-ul-li tree, to find only each uL's parent UL.
In the attached image I have highlighted the route/parents i need to obtain.
From there I can access each's checkbox.
There are sibling  elements, but i don't need those.
i have tried variations on the beneath jquery functions (all commented out)<, but no success.

```js
$(function ()
 {
  $(".subtree-checkbox").click(function (e)
  {
   var id = $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("id");

                        //var arr = $(this).parents("ul").attr("id");
   //var parent2 = $(this).parent("ul").find("ul").attr("id");

                         var myArray = [];
   //var parentEls = $(this).parents("ul").find("input[type=checkbox]")
   //var parentEls = $(this).parents().find("ul").attr("id")
    .map(function ()
    {
     //alert(this.id);
     myArray.push(this.id);
    })
    .get()
    .join(", ");
   alert(myArray.length);
      
                       $.each(myArray, function (key, value)
   {
    //alert(key + ": " + value);
                      });
      
                });
     
       });
```

```
<body>
<ul class="nav nav-list" id="MM0" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none;">
    <li>
        <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMenu_DTID1">
            <span class="checkbox MMTree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted1" class="MMTree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted0" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
            <input name="MM_IsPermitted1" type="hidden" value="false">
            Admin
        </span>
        <ul class="nav nav-list collapse in" id="MMenu_DTID1" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 20px;">
            <li>
                <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu_1">
                    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted1" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted1" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                    <input name="SM_IsPermitted1" type="hidden" value="false">
                    Debtors-Creditors
                </span>
                <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="MMenu_DTID1" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 20px;">
                    <li>
                        <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMenu_DTID110">
                            <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                            Read
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMenu_DTID110">
                            <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                            Create
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMenu_DTID110">
                            <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                            Update
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMenu_DTID110">
                            <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                            Delete
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1">
                    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted1" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted1" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                    <input name="SM_IsPermitted1" type="hidden" value="false">
                    Users
                </span>
                <ul class="nav nav-list collapse in" id="S_menu1" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 60px;">
                    <li>
                        <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu11">
                            <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled green red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted11" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted11" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="2"></span>
                            <input name="SM_IsPermitted11" type="hidden" value="false">
                            new subby tst3
                        </span>
                        <ul class="nav nav-list collapse in" id="S_menu11" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 20px;">
                            <li>
                                <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1110">
                                    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                                    Read
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1110">
                                    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                                    Create
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1110">
                                    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                                    Update
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1110">
                                    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                                    Delete
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each nested ul - get its ancestral li using .closest(). Then simply get the id of that li's parent() which will give you a series of ids - I am console logging the parent and child ul id's.

Incidentally in the provided nested list - you have two instances of the same id (MMenu_DTID1) so that should be amended.

```js
$('ul').each(function(){
 var el = $(this).attr('id');
 var parent = $(this).closest('li').parent().attr('id');
 parent == undefined
  ? console.log('Root UL id is ' + el )
  : console.log(parent + ' > ' + el);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-list" id="MM0" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none;">
    <li>
        <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMenu_DTID1">
            <span class="checkbox MMTree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted1" class="MMTree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted1" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
            <input name="MM_IsPermitted1" type="hidden" value="false">
            Admin
        </span>
        <ul class="nav nav-list collapse in" id="MMenu_DTID1" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 20px;">
            <li>
                <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu_1">
                    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted1" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted1" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                    <input name="SM_IsPermitted1" type="hidden" value="false">
                    Debtors-Creditors
                </span>
                <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="MMenu_DTID1" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 20px;">
                    <li>
                        <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMenu_DTID110">
                            <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                            Read
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMenu_DTID110">
                            <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                            Create
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMenu_DTID110">
                            <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                            Update
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MMenu_DTID110">
                            <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                            Delete
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1">
                    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted1" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted1" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                    <input name="SM_IsPermitted1" type="hidden" value="false">
                    Users
                </span>
                <ul class="nav nav-list collapse in" id="S_menu1" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 60px;">
                    <li>
                        <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu11">
                            <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled green red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted11" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted11" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="2"></span>
                            <input name="SM_IsPermitted11" type="hidden" value="false">
                            new subby tst3
                        </span>
                        <ul class="nav nav-list collapse in" id="S_menu11" aria-expanded="true" style="padding-left: 20px;">
                            <li>
                                <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1110">
                                    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                                    Read
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1110">
                                    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                                    Create
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1110">
                                    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                                    Update
                                </span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="accordion-heading" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#S_menu1110">
                                    <span class="checkbox subtree-checkbox styled red"><input name="SM_IsPermitted10" class="subtree-checkbox styled red" id="SM_IsPermitted10" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="false" iid="1"></span>
                                    Delete
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I just noticed the duplicated id's as well,..it's all generated from c#.

Comment: It's v.close,..I just need to filter  out the extras ..to get the UL's which are highighted as per in the image, i.e. not the other siblings and other ULs in the html.

Comment: "Note: the markup given is not the entire markup. There are many many other sub menus under the root, each of which has further submenus (i.e. <Ul> with <li> s in them. so the above solution returns several hundred id's.
I just need the direct parents as yellow highlighted in the image supplied.
Possibly a recursive function, which gets each successive parent UL?                Maybe implement some jquery not filter?